# How does coercion work?

Tags: iphone, ios, coercion

I just created a normal MyClass and defined an instance variable

```
@interface MyMFMessageComposeViewController : NSObject
{
    NSString *body;
    NSArray * recipients; 
}

@property (readwrite, strong) NSString *body;
@property (readwrite, strong) NSArray * recipients; 
@end
```

then I coreced to `MFMessageComposeViewController`.

and it worked - surprisingly - for some reason the class variables got transferred correcty.

**How does this work? Does the runtime really search for class variable NAMES to find the appropriate class variables?**

I thought coercion would just be an overlay of memory.

Many thanks for your insight?

Comment: What do you mean by "coerce"? Casting? isa-swizzling? You have also not shown enough code to figure out what has managed to "work".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objective-C is weakly typed (some people even say it's untyped), meaning that that the exact type of an object doesn't matter, as long as it responds to all of the selectors (method names) the program tries to send it.

MyMFMessageComposeViewController and MFMessageComposeViewController both have methods called `body`, `setBody`, `recipients`, and `setRecipients` because both classes declare and synthesize properties named body and recipients. (Remember that synthesizing properties just creates these accessor methods.)  If you access the member variables from an external object, you're using these methods, **even if you use dot notation to do it**.

In short, you're not accessing the instance variables directly; instead, you're using accessor methods, and because Objective-C doesn't care about the type of an object when it invokes methods, it all works just fine.

All that being said, you should delete this class and replace it with a proper subclass, at which point you (probably) won't have to worry about typecasting.

Comment: thank you very much for this clear explanation! by the way, the reason I cannot subclass MFMessageComposeViewController, is because in the simulator it returns always nil when trying to create a new instance. - But with your explanation I feel fine - since I just use this class during development anyway so I do not need to send real SMSs.

Comment: ps - just to make clear - so coercion as well uses these setters and getters? So there must be a loop through all the attributes of the object on the right side getting their values and using a corresponding setters for the object on the left side in the assignment: MFMessageComposeViewController* realObj = (MFMessageComposeViewController) myObj;

Comment: That assignment doesn't make a lot of sense unless `myObj` is really a `MFMessageComposeViewController*` (note the star). In that case, you're just copying the pointer `myObj` to the pointer `realObj` -- you're not creating a different object.

Comment: @user387184 - The type just doesn't matter.  You could declare an object as `id whatIsThis`, and as long as whatever pointer you assign to whatIsThis is an instance of a class that implements the method in question (whether we're talking getters, setters, or any other method), it will work.  (You've already proved this if you've ever called `[sender frame]` in an action method.)  If the class doesn't implement the method, your app will crash.  If you want to know more about the "magic" that makes this happen, look up objc_msgSend().